# C++ lambda lexical closure over local variables

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

**Summary**

In C++, when I return a lambda from a function that's captured a variable local to that function, what specifically happens, and why? The compiler (g++) seems to allow it, but it gives me different results than I was expecting, so I'm not sure if this is technically safe/supported.

**Details**

In some languages (Swift, Lisp, etc.) you can capture local variables in a closure/lambda, and they stay valid and in scope as long as the closure is in scope (I've heard it called "lambda over let over lambda" in a Lisp context). For example, in Swift, the example code for what I'm trying to do is:

```
func counter(initial: Int) -> (() -> Int) {
    var count = initial
    return { count += 1; return count }
}

let c = counter(initial: 0)
c() // returns 1
c() // returns 2
c() // returns 3
```

I tried to write a C++ equivalent of this like the following:

```
auto counter(int initial)
{
    int count = initial;
    return [&count] () -> int {
        count = count + 1;
        return count;
    };
}
```

However, the result I get is:

```
auto c = counter(0);
std::cout << c() << std::endl; // prints 1
std::cout << c() << std::endl; // prints 1
std::cout << c() << std::endl; // prints 1
```

If I capture a variable that's *still in scope*, it works as I'd expect. For example, if I do all of the following in a single function:

```
int count = 0;
auto c = [&count] () -> int {
    count = count + 1;
    return count;
};
std::cout << c() << std::endl; // prints 1
std::cout << c() << std::endl; // prints 2
std::cout << c() << std::endl; // prints 3
```

So I guess my question is, in the first C++ example above, what is actually getting captured? And is it defined behavior, or do I just have a reference to some random memory on the stack?

Comment: I don't understand this line `auto c = counter();`. How can you call the function without an argument? Seems like this wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @Richard, fixed, sorry about that.

Comment: You just have a reference to some random memory on the stack in first case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    return [&count] () -> int {
```

This is a capture by reference. The lambda captures a reference to this object.

The object in question, `count`, is in the function's local scope, so when the function returns, `count` gets destroyed, and this becomes a reference to an object that went out of scope and gets destroyed. Using this reference becomes undefined behavior.

Capturing by value seems to solve this problem:

```
    return [count] () -> int {
```

But your obvious intent is so that each invocation of this lambda returns a monotonically-increasing counter value. And merely capturing the object by value is not enough. You also need to use a [mutable lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
 return [count] () mutable -> int
 {
    return ++count;
 };
```

But the pedantical answer to your question "what happens" is that a lambda is essentially an anonymous class, and what a lambda captures are really class members. Your lambda is equivalent to:

```
class SomeAnonymousClassName {

     int &count;

public:
     SomeAnonymousClassName(int &count) : count(count)
     {}

     int operator()
     {
          // Whatever you stick in your lambda goes here.
     }
};
```

Capturing something by reference translates to a class member that's a reference. Capturing something by value translates to a class member that's not a reference, and the act of capturing lambda variables translates to passing them to the lambda class's constructor, which is what happens when you create a lambda. A lambda is really an instance of an anonymous class, with a defined `operator()`.

In a regular lambda, the `operator()` is actually a `const` operator method. In a mutable lambda, the `operator()` is a non-`const`, a mutable operator method.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why my edit mistakenly remove your last paragraph

Comment: Ahh cool. Thanks for the good explanation and the pointer to mutable lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are capturing a reference to a local variable. The reference becomes a dangling reference after the function returns. Hence, your program is subject to undefined behavior.